# Unexpected logout when testing with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain, capybara

I'm currently use devise as authentication and capybara + rspec as my test environment.

And there is a strange behavior that the admin seems like be logged out unexpectedly.

Here is my testing Code

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                                               
require 'helpers/myapp/login_helper'                                                        

describe "Crawler" do                                                                               
  describe "UpdateMainMenus" do                                                                     
    it "should work" do

      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:myapp_admin)

      login_as @admin, :scope => :admin
      visit admin_cron_jobs_url(subdomain: "myapp")
      current_url.should == admin_cron_jobs_url(subdomain: "myapp")

      puts ""
      puts current_url

      visit admin_cron_jobs_url(subdomain: "myapp")
      current_url.should == admin_cron_jobs_url(subdomain: "myapp")                                


      puts ""
      puts current_url

    end                                                                                             
  end
end
```

And the helpers/myapp/login_helper.rb

```
include Warden::Test::Helpers    
Warden.test_mode!
```

And I have set the Warden in rspec_helper.rb

```
config.after(:each) { Warden.test_reset! }
```

And the output is:

```
http://myapp.example.com/admin/cron_jobs
F

Failures:

  1) Crawler UpdateMainMenus should work
     Failure/Error: current_url.should == admin_cron_jobs_url(subdomain: "myapp")
       expected: "http://myapp.example.com/admin/cron_jobs"
            got: "http://myapp.example.com/admins/sign_in" (using ==)
     # ./spec/requests/myapp/crawler_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.44 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Any help is appreciated.. really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got it!

The admin did logged in. But in the second "visit", it did not logged in.

And the reason is that the session can not be kept between request since my session_store is not set correctly

Here is the origin setting:

```
if not Rails.env.production?
  MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                         key: '_myapp_session',
                                         domain: '.lvh.me'
end
```

Working version (ignore production setting) :

```
if Rails.env.development?
  MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                         key: '_myapp_session',
                                         domain: '.lvh.me'
elsif Rails.env.test?
  MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                         key: '_myapp_session',
                                         domain: :all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just don't login successfully ?

Comment: as you can see the output, the "first" printed out current_path is `http://myapp.example.com/admin/cron_jobs`, that is, the login is successfully at the first time